# How to click on image/button using java selenium chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to clik one button, as of now I'm using a XPATH, but sometime the page is changed and I've to update the XPATH.

I'm checking a different way (search and click a image like play.png, click by text, etc.), in order to obtain same result.

Following the portion of the HTML code:

```
<button class="btn btn-green false">PLAY</button>
```

EDIT:

I've tried with the code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),’PLAY’]")).click();
```

but it goes in exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[contains(text(),’PLAY’] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
at seleniumTest.TestSelenium.play(TestSelenium.java:300)
at seleniumTest.TestSelenium.open_url(TestSelenium.java:277)
at seleniumTest.TestSelenium.seleniumTest(TestSelenium.java:108)
at seleniumTest.TestSelenium.main(TestSelenium.java:85)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(text(),’PLAY’] because of the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(text(),’PLAY’]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Comment: In entire HTML, there is only one button with text `PLAY`? Or there could be more?

Comment: Yes, there is only one text PLAY.

Comment: I have a feeling this has something to do with having the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use contains or starts-with() when the values of the attributes are dynamic i.e. changing like:

```
//*[contains(text(),’PLAY’)]
```

Comment: @GabrielePanarese try this `//*[contains(text(),'PLAY')]` , the problem at answer it's the char `’`. It should be `'` or `"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find something that doesn't change.

For example you could do that in XPath using wildcard:

```
//button[text()='PLAY']
```

Also you could use the other ways to identify elements in Selenium.

For example `By.id(...)` if your elements have a unique id.

See [Selenium doc for class By](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)

Comment: unfortunately there's not a ID, with your example it works but only with particular resolution screen, I cannot understand why. The HTML code remains same in all cases.

Comment: Is your button visible? Only visible elements can be clicked.